# What is the correct physical fitness path here?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, weight-gain, health

When a person feels that s/he is "out of shape".  Should the goal be to lose weight, or to improve health regardless of what that does to the number on the scale?  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal should never be weight loss. Body weight can vary from day to day, time of the day and many other factors.

**Exercise**

Do whatever you like, but do something. Some people swear by running but this has always ruined my knees. It should be something they are motivated to do, be it walking the dog, going for a swim or pounding a heavy bag down the gym.

**Eat right**

Your body will tell you if you're feeding it crap. If you feel bad after eating it, this a pretty good sign it isn't doing you any good.

For example, this isn't my favourite meal, but it makes me feel I could take on Mike Tyson!

- Boiled rice
- Steamed white fish
- Corn fed chicken
- Spinach (or some other green leafy vegetable)
- Chinese tea